# Unable to log in using Chrome browser

Tags: authentication-authorization

I having an issue with my Drupal site (8.9.19)

Using Firefox browser, there is no problem login for all users

However, when using Chrome - users are unable to access. This is what I received in the Recent log message:-

1. When an user has successfully login, the Recent log message shows "Session opened for theusernameperson." - This is OK
2. However, in the Recent log message - there is another line that shows "Path: /home. Drupal\Core\Http\Exception\CacheableAccessDeniedHttpException: The 'access content' permission is required. in Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess() (line 117 of /var/www/mywebsite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php)." The User is "Anonymous (not verified)"

I've no issue login using the same usernames in Firefox

a) I have checked both Server (info.php) and Browser client - there are having the same date and time

b) All blocks in the block layouts are also set to Authenticated users only.

It is running on non secure server (http)

Using Microsoft Edge also produces the same error. The only 2 browsers I can access without issue are Firefox (desktop and mobile) and Huawei Browser (mobile)

Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Do anonymous users have the **access content** permission?

Comment: Does your application working other browser? If yes then clear the Browser cache and try. Also clear Drupal cache as well from app side.

Comment: Anonymous users does not have access content permission because this whole drupal site is meant for local users only - for company employees. No outside users allowed. Even if an outside user manage to know the url of certain content page, the first page they see is the login page

Yes, it works in Firefox - after login page, it goes to the Front Page. As for chrome browser cache, it has been removed. Same goes to Drupal cache using Performance - Clear all caches